# Can I fill a 2d array with arraylists?

Tags: java, class, object, println

I have 2 different type of objects:

```
public class Students{
   protected String name;
   protected int age;

}

public class InternationalStudents extends Students{
   private String nationality;

}
```

And I have an arraylist that contains 4 Objects, 2 students, and 2 int.students.

I have a function like this:

```
filling(Arraylist<Students> list,Students[][] objects) {   
 .......}
```

I would like to fill the 2d array to look like this:

```
{ {name,age},{name,age},
  {name,age,nationality},{name,age,nationality}
}
```

The important part is the printing after the filling. It should look like a matrix, for example:

```
Jim : 15  |  Jacob: 16
Juan: 18  |  Leonardo: 15
```

Can anyone help with the filling function?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Saying that "after filling it, it should look like a matrix" is a strange thing to say. It'll be an array of arrays, how you print it is up to you. But yes you can have a 2D array of `ArrayList` objects. Maybe take a beginner's Java tutorial on arrays and lists and it should give you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
  Student[][] objects =
      list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o instanceof InternationalStudent,
                   Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                                                a -> a.toArray(new Student[0]))))
          .values()
          .stream()
          .toArray(Student[][]::new);
```